# magento - index management - Cannot initialize the indexer process

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I've just moved my Magento site to a new server and I'm trying to re-index my store using the Index Management.

I check all the boxes and re-index and I get the following:

`Cannot initialize the indexer process.`

I've looked at resetting the file permissions using the Magento Cleanup tool. But nothing I've tried seems to work.

Has anyone ever come across this before and how did they get past this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any idea why you can't do it from the Index Management, but as a temporary solution, I would advise to use indexer.php script from the cmd line:
`php /var/www/magento/shell/indexer.php reindexall`. You can also run it by the system cron periodically, it should do the trick for a while.

Answer (score 0):

delete files from var/locks and change permission of folder to 755, it will work..if donot have any issue with Dataseb files